# Evaluate ValueExpression in ResourceHandler with Apache CODI

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere, cdi, codi

My Webapp is running on Websphere 8.0.0.2 with Apache CODI 1.0.1 and I have an issue related to the ResourceHandler implementation of primefaces.

Primefaces evaluates a value expression within the resource handler to retrieve dynamic content, why and how is not important. The fact is, that the ResourceHandler is called before everything else within the JSF Lifecycle.

I am using the ViewAccessScope for the bean which should be evaluated with the value expression within the ResourceHandler. I debugged into it and found out that the CODI-Wrapper for the ValueExpression tries to retriev the view root of the FacesContext or more exactly the view id of it. The problem is, that the view root is null at that time, so the evaluation ends with a NullPointerException in a CODI class.

Who is responsible for this issue, on which issue tracker should i post a bug?
I would also appreciate suggestions for workarounds :D

Answer (score 0):

> *a NullPointerException in a CODI class.*

If the `NullPointerException` isn't caused by any of the arguments/variables which you, as enduser, can have control over, and it's not *explicitly* been thrown or asserted by the code, then it's likely a bug in the CODI class. Report it to CODI.

Comment: I already did, the problem I see is that if a ResourceHandler is invoked, the JSF Lifecycle is not invoked at all. As far as I know the fact that the ViewRestore Phase is not invoked will break the functionallity of the ViewAccessScope. The problem is probably with the implementation of primefaces.

Comment: As I learned today it is not a bug of MyFaces CODI. I read http://myfaces.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.myfaces.users+page:1+mid:kz6obow6nk3s7e34+state:results

Answer (score 0):

Solutions I found:
http://myfaces.markmail.org/thread/kuoredrgrpqnfwgl
impl.:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3549#c4

or

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17609&p=57393#p57393

Comment: Thanks for adding the links, it was me posting that stuff.